# Can I head a file in tramp?

Tags: emacs, ssh, head, tramp

Say I want to tramp a remote file in Emacs. If the file is huge, this could take a long time.

Can I tell Emacs/Tramp to only head or display/retrieve part of it?

Answer (score 4):

You can open the directory that the file is in, and type <kbd>M-!</kbd> `head my_file`.  The command gets executed over SSH.

The function `insert-file-contents` takes optional arguments that specify which portion of the file to insert, and from a quick glance it seems like Tramp tries to extract only the parts it needs.  You'd need to write an interactive function on top of that, though.

Comment: or alternatively, open the directory the file is in, move point to the file in question, and type `! head RET`